# Printing docstrings in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, docstring

How do you print doc strings in python 3.1.x?
I tried with the re and sys modules as a test and I keep getting errors. Thanks

```
import re
print(re._doc_)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#91>", line 1, in <module>
    print(re._doc_)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_doc_'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called `__doc__`, not `_doc_`.

```
import re
print(re.__doc__)
```

Works just fine.

Comment: Thanks, I missed the double underscores!